# Powershell - Get-ChildItems -recurse not working

Tags: powershell

i am new to powershell and struggling a bit.

```
$SOURCE="\\server\folder\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4"
$TYPE='*.csv'
$SUB="*subx*
Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $SOURCE -include $TYPE -filter $SUB
```

In my head this is to search a network path folder for folders below "sub4" that are all named "subx" if that makes sense.

Then want to return a list of files that are XX*.csv (csv's that start with XX) that are present in the subfolders that exist in sub folders below these "subx" folders.

so the paths may end up being

```
"\\server\folder\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4\xxxxx\yyyyy\subx\zzzzzzz\XX*.csv"
"\\server\folder\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4\aaaaa\bbbbb\subx\ccccccc\XX*.csv"
```

But it doesnt work, it only returns 1 file with subx in the name ending in .csv

I can run this and it returns the list of folders/files called "subx" but it doesnt recurse through the subfolders below subx

```
$SOURCE="\\server\folder\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4"
$SUB="*subx*
Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $SOURCE -filter $SUB
```

I can run this and it returns all files called XX*.csv in the sub folders below the $SOURCE path

```
$SOURCE="\\server\folder\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4"
$TYPE='*.csv'
Get-ChildItem -recurse -path $SOURCE -include $TYPE
```

any tips would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Is the `x` in `subx` supposed to be a placeholder for a digit (eg. folder named "sub7"), or a literal `x`?

Comment: Did you mean `Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCE -Filter 'XX*.csv' -File -Recurse` perhaps?

Comment: It's a literal x, could be 'a' but the idea is that this is a common folder name across the many different folder subpaths for example there could be a folder called sub y with a .csv in but i only want the ones with subx as the folder "\\server\folder\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4\xxxxx\yyyyy\subx\zzzzzzz\XX*.csv"
"\\server\folder\sub1\sub2\sub3\sub4\xxxxx\yyyyy\suby\zzzzzzz\XX*.csv"

Comment: is the order of the -recurse sensitive?

Comment: @Theo also i tried what you suggested and it does not "filter" only those files in subfolders that have "subx" in the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the operation into 2 steps:

- Discover the `subx` folders under `sub4`
- Discover the `*.csv` files under each of those

Note: *In the following example I'm deliberate avoiding `-Include` because it's **terribly slow** in combination with `-Recurse`.*

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SOURCE -Directory -Recurse -Filter subx |Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.csv
```

Comment: works perfectly, i take it i need to understand the -directory and -file commands a bit better, joining commands??   And its much quicker than manual searching!

Comment: `-File` just filters the result so you only receive matching files (no directory), and vice versa with `-Directory`. The "joining" of two commands into a single pipeline will make the first command output it's results one-by-one, and the subsequent command can then repeat for each input item (as in this case)